# ASP.NET - Can't save changes on GridView because of button Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, and buttons that do actions (Edit, Save, etc). The GridView is created dynamically. **Once I press Edit button, I add textbox (controls) on every cell of the GridView**, with their respective text value, so it can be edited.

The problem comes **when I click Save button, because when the method starts, it seems like there isn't any textbox in the gridview**... so that makes me think if it's because some autopostback stuff when the Save button it's clicked.

Any thoughts about solving that?

EDIT: Clarifying what I want:

1) I got a gridview with data,
2) I put the data of each cell from each row into textboxes,
3) I put those textboxes in the gridview,
4) I do change data in those textboxes,
5) **I can't save that data because when I click the Save button, the data on the textboxes deletes itself**

Comment: you should share some code to make your problems clearer.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Like previous comment, please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide us some code.

Comment: @Homungus I just want to edit data from a gridview and then save it. I guess there's no code needed to understand that

Comment: @404pio I have clarifyied what i meant on OP

Comment: @Angel showing some code makes it easier for the community to see, what effort you made to find a solution and where you are mistaken. If you just write: 'I want to achieve this and that, please code that for me' there will probably nobody there to help you.

Comment: Vote to close the question, because it was again asked here, with code examples this time..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407397/asp-net-cant-save-changes-from-gridview-to-database

Comment: @Homungus Yes i know, but it doesn't let me delete, it says "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid postbacks, ASP.NET works with them.
When you click the save button, the page does postback and the Load event fires. In that event, you have to rebuild the page as before you clicked Save (put the textboxes).
If you don't do it, the textboxes aren't there no more and no text can be saved.

Edit: gives unique names to your textboxes, it seems non-sense, but ASP.NET need to hooks on names

Comment: Yes, I solved the textbox problem inserting the gridview with textboxes on a Session variable. The actual problem is the text i've written on those textboxes is still being deleted on postback. How could i save the data written on textboxes?

Comment: If you rebuild the page exactly as it was before the postback, the values should be there